# 1:N joins of KSQL streams and tables

Tags: ksqldb

I'm currently using Debezium to stream events from two tables of a commercial application, INVOICE and INVOICE_LINE. As you can guess by the names, there is a 1:N relationship between the two tables, per invoice there will be a line in INVOICE table and N in INVOICE_LINE.

```
INVOICE
-------------
 ID
 DESCRIPTION
 INVOICE_DATE
 STATUS
-------------
```

```
INVOICE_LINE
------------
 ID        
 INVOICE_ID
 DESCRIPTION
 AMOUNT
 PRICE
 CURRENCY
------------
```

Invoices are initially created in status 'NEW' but they are not officially finished (and therefore ready for additional processing) until they are in status 'PROCESSED'.

Using the topics created by Debezium, I would like to provide my consumer the invoices that have changed their status to 'PROCESSED' (header and lines). Between the initial creation of the invoice and when the status changes to 'PROCESSED' there could be several days of difference.

Due to this, my strategy was to create a KSQL table with the invoice_lines and join it with a filtered KSQL stream of processed invoices. However, this seems to not be possible as only the key of the KSQL can be used for joining. It is usually recommended to re-key the KSQL table for this case, however as there could be more than one INVOICE_LINE per INVOICE this will not work on my case.

What's the recommended approach for a 1:N join like the one I described above?

Comment: KSQL does not yet support 1:N joins: https://github.com/confluentinc/ksql/issues/4424

Comment: Thank you for mentioning the issue. By any chance you know if there is a way to workaround this limitation?